# Swift Notifications multiple Banners

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I know this topic is familiar, but I have a huge problem with the notification banners. I already studied the most stackoverflow threads about this topic, but there weren't the correct answers.

My problem: I want to repeat a Notification every day at 10 pm. It repeats correctly, on the first and second day. On the third and fourth day it repeated 3 times at 10pm with the same banner.

This is my code:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: [.alert,.sound])
    {
        (granted, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("granted, but Error in notification permission:\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    notificationContent.title = "Diary of Health"
    notificationContent.body = "Wie war dein Tag?"

    var date = DateComponents()
    date.hour = 22
    date.minute = 00
    date.second = 00
    let notificationTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: date, repeats: true)

    let notificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "\(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)", content: notificationContent, trigger: notificationTrigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(notificationRequest) { (error) in
        if let error = error
        {
            let errorString = String(format: NSLocalizedString("Unable to Add Notification Request %@, %@", comment: ""), error as CVarArg, error.localizedDescription)
            print(errorString)
        }
    }
```

Very straight forward, very easy, you might think ...

What I already tried:
- Installing the application completely new
- Installing it with a new bundleId
- Updated my iOS because of the previous bug in iOS 9.X

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: I think your problem is scheduling notifications. Maybe you’ve called this code multiple time or whatever. Where you’ve called this code? Also I don’t understand to your identifier.

Comment: @Mannopson Yeah I thought of this, too. Maybe I have to include the code into my "firstLaunch" function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling [removeAllPendingNotificationRequests](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649509-removeallpendingnotificationrequ) before adding one.

Every time you call "add" it adds a new one (even though the title/body/time is the same).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your fast reply. I will try this and give you a feedback as fast as possible.

Comment: Where Do I have to call "removeAllPendingNotificationRequests"?

Comment: "Update": Nice. It worked for the first day. I am looking forward to the next one.